# download webpage by asp.net

Tags: asp.net, download, html

given a url how can i download the webpage to my harddrive with asp.net

e.g. if you open the url http://www.cnn.com in ie6 and use file save as, it will download the html page to your system.

how can i achieve this by asp.net

Comment: Just the HTML or the HTML and images?

Answer (score 3):

As [womp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371406/download-webpage-by-asp-net/1371426#1371426) said, using WebClient is simpler in my opinion. Here is my simpler example :

```
string result;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    result = client.DownloadString(address);
}
// Just save the result to a file or do what you want..
```

Comment: I knew they had to already have done this! +1

Comment: I can able to do this, which downloads source code of that page.
        Using client As New WebClient()
            client.DownloadFile("http://www.cnn.com", "c:\test.html")
        End Using

but what i am missing in this are the image downloads. from the above i am getting only the image location not the real images itself.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.  But you will need to consider security if you are doing it from within an ASP.NET page.

```
public static void GetFromHttp(string URL, string FileName)
        {
            HttpWebRequest HttpWReq = CreateWebRequest(URL);

            HttpWebResponse HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();
            Stream readStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();
            Byte[] read = new Byte[256];

            Stream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            int count = readStream.Read(read, 0 , 256);
            while (count > 0) 
            {
                fs.Write(read, 0, count);
                count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
            }
            readStream.Close();

            HttpWResp.Close();
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

Stream data = client.OpenRead ("http://www.myurl.com");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine (s);
data.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Comment: You really should be using using. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.cnn.com";
var hwr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
using (var r = hwr.GetResponse()) 
using (var s = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Console.Write(s.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: here i have only html, i am looking for a htm folder where it will have all the images of the url