# Metadescription tag

Tags: asp.net, xml

How to find that a web page, other from current page,contain any metadescripition tag or not,
actually it is very simple for current page you just have to write page.metadescriptio!=null,
but how we can find about other website like google,facebook..etc contains metadescription tag or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is possible only if you load the webpage, parse the HTML and chech if meta tag description exist in the page or not.

You can use [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371406/download-webpage-by-asp-net) to find out how to get a web page content using C#.net.

Now you just have to find all meta tags and see if one of the tags represent the description of the page. You can use this function to find if there are ant meta description

```
string html = GetHtml(string url);
html.IndexOf("name=\"description\"");
```